# Manage mySQL DB by using phpMyAdmin and point browser to ip

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi I am completely new to phpMyAdmin and mySQL

Is there any way to configure remote management/access of my MySQL database by pointing requests or a browser to an IP? I have my server set up behind a router and have setup port forwarding for ports 8080 (tomcat) and 3306(should be default mySQL). Everything works locally on the machine, however I cannot access the dbs or phpmyadmin by pointing a browser from a computer on the local network to http://IP/phpmyadmin or from externally by pointing the browser to the IP given to me by my ISP. Any thoughts? Is there a specific way to edit the config files in order to allow the use of IP addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exposing your db and appserver on the internet is not a good idea. If these need to be accessed remotely, use a VPN or authenticated SSL. In the case of phpmyadmin - if this is running on a webserver on your network then you'll need to forward port 80 too - although I'd recommend using HTTPS/SSL (port 443)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem and good call on the https, this isn't anything important but the extra layer of security never hurt!